# High speed signals to FPGA

Tags: fpga, termination, bnc

I want to take 30ns pulse signals from BNC cables and send them to pins on an FPGA board. I have the board in a metal box with ungrounded BNC connectors mounted on it. What's the best way to pass the signal a few more inches to the board without getting reflections on the lines? Can I just use a twisted pair of wires and terminate it with 50 ohms? Should I use RG316 cable? Should I connect all the ground lines at a single point and connect that to the box?

Comment: A 50 Ohm resistor will give you the best signal integrity assuming 50 Ohm source and cable. Not every source is going to be happy driving a 50 Ohm load, though. Have you already viewed the pulse signal when terminated in 50 Ohms?

Answer (score 1):

30 ns implies a corresponding wavelength of about 18 meters. If you don't make your edges too fast (say, target 8-10 ns rise and fall times), you should be able to route this a few inches without worrying about impedance matching.

I'd just use a ribbon cable for this connection.

You will need a common ground between the remote box and the FPGA board. You can use additional wires in the ribbon cable to provide that. The more wires you dedicate to ground, the less cross-talk you'll have between your signals. Having equal number of ground and signal wires is safest, but probably more than you need. Having just one ground wire is risky. Somewhere in between is your optimum cost/performance point.